# Having Issue On DataTables Download File Name

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am using DataTable to download table value to Excel and CSV as following code

```
var allDataTbl = $('#all-data-tbl').DataTable( {
        bFilter: false,
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [  'copy', 'excel', 'csv' ]
    } );
```

but the downloaded file is getting a dummy long name like

> BC Run of River Decision Support ToolChart context menuChart context
>   menuChart context menuChart context menuChart context menuChart
>   context menuChart context menuChart context menuChart context
>   menuChart context menuChart context menuChart.csv

which only the `BC Run of River Decision Support Tool` is correct! can you please let me know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, file name would be the title of your HTML page. To override the default value, use [`title`](http://datatables.net/reference/button/csv) option as follows:

```js
var allDataTbl = $('#all-data-tbl').DataTable( {
    searching: false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [  
        'copy', 
        {
           extend: 'excel', 
           title: 'filename'
        },
        {
           extend: 'csv', 
           title: 'filename'
        }
    ]
} );
```